# Codeigniter affected_rows for simple insert not working for SQL Server

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter

Note : I use SQL Server

This is my model code :

```
$this->db->insert('VOTER', array('voter_name' => $data['name'], 'event_id' => 1));
return $this->db->affected_rows() > 0;
```

The data inserted successfully, but the `affected_rows()` function break my PHP. There is no error, nor warning. When i try to `echo`/`print_r` the value of `affected_rows()`, it returns nothing (not null, just nothing).

If i `echo`/`print_r` after the `affected_rows()`, they will not shown because (i believe) my PHP has been stop.

The data is inserted successfully because it was inserted before i call  `affected_rows()`.

Please kindly help me

Thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: [This could be helpfull](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/issues/2794)

Comment: @karanthakkar Thanks a lot. What PHP file should i modify, according to the link?

Comment: Are you using CodeIgniter 2.x or 3? If it's the former, I'd highly suggest that you upgrade to 3 as soon as possible and it should fix not only this problem, but also hundreds of other bugs.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't mentioned in your question, but you're using CodeIgniter 2.x ... And you're seeing nothing because you've got the display_errors and/or error_reporting disabled.

`affected_rows()` doesn't work with the 'sqlsrv' driver in CI2 as it calls a non-existing function (there's a missing letter from the function call, to be more specific). In other words - it's a bug.

CodeIgniter 2 is in security maintenance mode until October 31st, 2015 (just a week away) and doesn't accept non-security patches, meaning that this bug will *not* be fixed. After October 31st, it will be completely abandoned and version 3 will be the only supported one.

The solution: Upgrade to the latest CodeIgniter 3.0.x version, *now*.

Answer (score -1):

In your code you are return  condition that's wrong. we use `if` to check condition

```
return $this->db->affected_rows() > 0;// wrong return
```

You have to do

```
if( $this->db->affected_rows() > 0)
 return $this->db->affected_rows();
else
FALSE;
```

Comment: there is nothing wrong with `return $this->db->affected_rows() > 0;` as you mentioned. it will return either `TRUE` or `FALSE`. the issue OP is facing is `affected_rows()` is not working properly in his case.

Comment: @karanthakkar if OP return `return $this->db->affected_rows() > 0;` and try to echo in controller then it show error. But if OP just `echo $this->db->affected_rows()` in model it will show the number of affected row

Answer (score -1):

Modify your code to be like this:

```
$this->db->insert('VOTER', array('voter_name' => $data['name'], 'event_id' => 1));
$insert_status = $this->db->affected_rows();
return $insert_status > 0 ? TRUE : FALSE;
```

Comment: No, because my problem is in `affected_rows()`, its not working (not returning any value). Thanks anyway :)